# Закрасить ячейку таблицы по клику мыши jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется обычный html код таблицы.
Как закрасить ячейку таблицы по нажатию кнопки мыши, а по повторному - убрать закрашивание. Просьба написать рабочий код, а не алгоритм. Спасибо.

Comment: вы ваш рабочий [mcve] приложите, тут помогают справиться с возникшими проблемами, а не делают за вас

Comment: задача элементарная, вы пробовали искать решение сами?

Comment: Да, пробовал, час наверно потратил, не один из способов у меня не заработал.

Comment: код ниже, на что час то? ваш пример приложите, где не работает

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('click');
        });
    });

Comment: что это? вы про что? дополните вопрос. Вам уже ответили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("colored");
});
```

```css
.colored {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Я понял в чем моя ошибка, я не подключил библиотеку jquery. Спасибо огромное